# How to format text file and export as html in Powershell?

Tags: regex, shell, powershell

How can I import a text file and use regex to format the text file then export it in HTML?

Answer (score 2):

To read a text file use `Get-Content file.txt`.  To massage the text using regex I would use the `-replace` operator.  Then just redirect the output to an html file e.g.:

```
$header = "<html><head>...</head><body>"
$body = Get-Content file.txt | Foreach {$_ -replace '^(.*)$','<p>$1</p>'}
$footer = "</body></html>"
$header + $body + $footer > file.html
```